# jQuery click function not working with jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to create a Java Web application. I have written a small piece of code but it isn't working.

Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Enter Search Item</title>   

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Search Item: <input type="text" name = "search" id= "search"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id ="button">
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() { 

        var searchTerm = $("#search").val();
        alert(searchterm);

        if(searchTerm == "")
            alert("Enter a valid search term");

    });  
});
```

When i click on button, it's not giving me an alert. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here

Comment: Please check for any errors. That should most certainly tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) since you're working with a jQuery object, change:

```
var searchTerm = $("#search").value;
```

To:

```
var searchTerm = $("#search").val();
```

You also have an inconsistency with your variable names (case matters with JS variables).

Change `alert(searchterm);` to `alert(searchTerm);` to match the case.

Comment: I changed it to. val(). But nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects have no `.value` property, thats a DOM element property. Use `.val()` for jQuery:

```
$("#search").val();
```

Or, regular DOM element:

```
$("#search")[0].value;
```